# Clojure spews out this error at the end of binary search. why? and how to avoid it?

Tags: exception, clojure

Here's the code, it is a straight forward binary search implementation.

```
    (defn binary_search
           "searches for a single element in a sorted array in logartihmic time"
           ([array start end element]
           (do (println "start " start " end " end " middle " (int (+ (/ (- end start)        2) start))) (
           (if (= (get array  (int (+ (/ (- end start) 2) start))) element) (println "element found at " (+ (int (/ (- end start) 2)) start))
              (if (= (- end start) 0) (do (println "not found :(") -1)
                 (if (> (get array (+ (int (/ (- end start) 2)) start)) element) (binary_search array start (dec (+ (int (/ (- end start) 2)) start)) element)
                   (binary_search array (inc (+ (int (/ (- end start) 2)) start)) end element))
  )))))
  ([array element] (do (println "starting binary search....") (binary_search array 0 (dec (count array)) element)))
)
```

The error i receive is at the end of every execution of the function. As you can see, it prints out "NullPointerException" if the element is found and a "ClassCastException" if it is not.

My thought on this is that it is trying to execute the return value as a function, where as it is not when the element is not found.

And, when it is found, It is not returning the value right there(which is expected), and it is trying to execute the statements after that, resulting in a NPE. Is that right?

```
=> (Clojure-First.core/binary_search [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 7)
starting binary search....
start  0  end  7  middle  3
start  4  end  7  middle  5
start  6  end  7  middle  6
element found at  6
NullPointerException   Clojure-First.core/binary-search (core.clj:49)
=> (Clojure-First.core/binary_search [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 8)
starting binary search....
start  0  end  7  middle  3
start  4  end  7  middle  5
start  6  end  7  middle  6
start  7  end  7  middle  7
element found at  7
NullPointerException   Clojure-First.core/binary-search (core.clj:49)
=> (Clojure-First.core/binary_search [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 1)
starting binary search....
start  0  end  7  middle  3
start  0  end  2  middle  1
start  0  end  0  middle  0
element found at  0
NullPointerException   Clojure-First.core/binary-search (core.clj:49)
=> (Clojure-First.core/binary_search [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 2)
starting binary search....
start  0  end  7  middle  3
start  0  end  2  middle  1
element found at  1
NullPointerException   Clojure-First.core/binary-search (core.clj:49)
=> (Clojure-First.core/binary_search [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 3)
starting binary search....
start  0  end  7  middle  3
start  0  end  2  middle  1
start  2  end  2  middle  2
element found at  2
NullPointerException   Clojure-First.core/binary-search (core.clj:49)
=> (Clojure-First.core/binary_search [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] 17
                                     )
starting binary search....
start  0  end  7  middle  3
start  4  end  7  middle  5
start  6  end  7  middle  6
start  7  end  7  middle  7
not found :(
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  Clojure-First.core/binary-search (core.clj:49)
```

Answer (score 3):

in this excerpt of your code:

```
 ...(
           (if (= (get array  (int...
```

you are calling the result of that conditional as if it were a function. The code is very hard to read, but I see no signs that it returns a function of no arguments.

PS. please try to use idiomatic style, in particular this code would be much more readable with [`let`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28let%20%5bbindings%2a%20%5d%20exprs%2a%29) bindings and line breaks.

the trivial fix is to add a call to println (or some other innocuous function) at that hanging open brace:

```
...(println
           (if (= (get array (int...
```

Better is to actually make readable and idiomatic Clojure code:

```
(defn binary-search
  "searches for a single element in a sorted array in logartihmic time"
  ([array start end element]
     (let [middle_exact (+ (/ (- end start) 2) start)
           middle (int middle_exact)
           middle-elt (get array (int middle))]
       (println "start " start " end " end " middle " middle)
       (cond 
        (= middle-elt element)
        (do (println "element found at " middle) middle)
        (or (= end middle) (= start middle))
        (do (println "not found :(") -1)
        (> middle-elt element)
        (recur array start (int (Math/floor (- end (/ middle_exact 2)))) element)
        :otherwise
        (recur array (int (Math/ceil (+ start (/ middle_exact 2)))) end element))))
  ([array element]
     (println "starting binary search....")
     (binary-search array 0 (dec (count array)) element)))
```

Comment: Hey, your code still throws the NPE whenever executed. It does not solve my issue, it simply makes the code cleaner.

Comment: double checking the code, I do see that `end element` in `end element)))` is extraneous and should be deleted, but due to the preceding `:otherwise` the code never gets there.

Comment: Which version of Clojure are u running? I get this error on tryclj.com - http://pastebin.com/HQaUNbqE. Locally I get this - http://pastebin.com/Lx3DbF2Y

Comment: This is a logic error in the search index selection - I attempted to do a literal translation of the existing logic, but it is erroneous

Comment: updated again, this time checked for every index, and for elements not present

Answer (score 2):

As noisesmith suggested, the cause of NPE is that you tried to perform function application against nil, which was the return value from println.

I just tried to tidy up the code.

```
(defn binary-search
  "Searches for a single element in a sorted vector in logarithmic time,
   and returns the index of the element if it exists, otherwise returns nil"
  ([v elem]
    ;(println "starting  binary search....")
    (binary-search v 0 (count v) elem))
  ([v start end elem]
    (let [index (+ start (quot (- end start) 2))]
      ;(println 'start start 'end end 'middle index)
      (if (<= start index (dec end))
        (let [mid (nth v index)]
          (cond (> mid elem) (recur v start index elem)
                (< mid elem) (recur v (inc index) end elem)
                :else index))
        nil))))
```

If you want to trace the execution, remove the ';' at the beginning of the lines commented out.